# Use of ol.source.BingMaps culture parameter

Tags: openlayers, parameters, bing-maps

I have noticed that even though openlayers 3 include the [culture](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.BingMaps.html) parameter when requesting the Bing maps layer, Bing maps itself does not support imagery for other languages except English [(supported codes)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx).

Is there a way to set the display language of Bing maps roads and places in openlayers 3 other than English and if so, how? I am interested in the Greek language

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/427/) to try your coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fiddle you posted is working as expected. If you specify a `culture: 'en-GB'` option, then OL3 will load the following image:

> https:// ecn.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r03311.jpeg?g=5413&**mkt=en-GB**&shading=hill

[image: en-GB image]

If you change the value of the `culture` option, then different tile URLs are requested:

> https:// ecn.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r03311.jpeg?g=5413&**mkt=es-ES**&shading=hill

[image]

That answers your question of "Is there a way to set the language of the placenames in the map tiles?". However, if you want to try that for the greek locale (`el`), the result is... the default tiles.

Now, if you have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx , you'll see that MS only offers localization of map tiles ("imagery") for a certain subset of cultures, and greek is not on the list. Unfortunately, you're out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

The link you provided is for the static imagery service and not for the Bing Maps tiles. Bing Maps supports a massive number of languages. Here is an exhaustive list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306047.aspx